# .net core websockets obtain DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am testing out .net core and making a small sample app using .net core + websockets to push some data into my app. I want to save this data in the database using a dbcontext.

However I have issues getting the dbcontext in my websocket handler. So how can I create a dbcontext to use.

My startup Configure method contains this:

```
...
app.Map("/ws", WSHandler.Map);
...
```

This is my WSHandler class that implements actually reading from the incoming connection. I need a DbContext here that I can use to read/write from the database.

```
/// <summary>
/// Handler for an incoming websocket client
/// </summary>
public class WSHandler {
    /// <summary>
    /// Max size in bytes of an incoming/outgoing message
    /// </summary>
    public const int BufferSize = 4096;

    /// <summary>
    /// The socket of the current connection
    /// </summary>
    WebSocket socket;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor, assign socket to current instance and adds socket to ConnectedClients. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="socket"></param>
    WSHandler(WebSocket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure app to use websockets and register handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    public static void Map(IApplicationBuilder app) {
        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.Use((WSHandler.Acceptor);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Accept HttpContext and handles constructs instance of WSHandler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hc">The HttpContext</param>
    /// <param name="n">Task n</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static async Task Acceptor(HttpContext hc, Func<Task> n) {
         if (hc.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest == false) {
            return; 
        }

        var socket = await hc.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
        var h = new WSHandler(socket);
        await h.Loop();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wait's for incoming messages 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    async Task Loop() {
        var buffer = new Byte[BufferSize];
        ArraySegment<Byte> segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);
        while (this.socket.State == WebSocketState.Open) {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;
            do {
                result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None);
            } while (result.EndOfMessage == false);

            // do something with message here. I want to save parse and save to database
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, @John Smith. Have you resolved this issue? I'm looking for the solution now

Comment: @Mergasov yes let me go to the code and I will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is some interests in this post I have added the solution I used.

You have access to all services via the `HttpContext`. So what I did is get the context options from this service and then create context when I need them. Be aware though that long living contexts are not advised and if an error occurs a DbContext is no longer useable. In the end I implemented a different database caching layer and write to that instead of using DbContext itself in the websocket handler.

Here is the code above extended to create DbContexts. I have not tested it since right now I don't have visual studio available...

```
 <summary>
/// Handler for an incoming websocket client
/// </summary>
public class WSHandler {
    /// <summary>
    /// Max size in bytes of an incoming/outgoing message
    /// </summary>
    public const int BufferSize = 4096;

    /// <summary>
    /// The socket of the current connection
    /// </summary>
    WebSocket socket;

    /// <summary>
    /// The options to create DbContexts with.
    /// </summary>
    DbContextOptions<AssemblyServerContext> ctxOpts;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor, assign socket to current instance and adds socket to ConnectedClients. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="socket"></param>
    /// <param name="ctxOpts"></param>
    WSHandler(WebSocket socket, DbContextOptions<AssemblyServerContext> ctxOpts) {
        this.ctxOpts = ctxOpts;
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure app to use websockets and register handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    public static void Map(IApplicationBuilder app) {
        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.Use((WSHandler.Acceptor);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Accept HttpContext and handles constructs instance of WSHandler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hc">The HttpContext</param>
    /// <param name="n">Task n</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static async Task Acceptor(HttpContext hc, Func<Task> n) {
         if (hc.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest == false) {
            return; 
        }

        var socket = await hc.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
        var ctxOptions = hc.RequestServices.GetService<DbContextOptions<AssemblyServerContext>>();
        var h = new WSHandler(socket, ctxOptions);
        await h.Loop();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wait's for incoming messages 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    async Task Loop() {
        var buffer = new Byte[BufferSize];
        ArraySegment<Byte> segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);
        while (this.socket.State == WebSocketState.Open) {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;
            do {
                result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None);
            } while (result.EndOfMessage == false);

            // do something with message here. I want to save parse and save to database
            using (var ctx = new AssemblyServerContext(ctxOpts)) {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you handle this using the caching layer?

Comment: @jpdesigning I can't really give the code since I don't have access to it anymore. What I ended up doing is having a long running background thread that reads from a threadsafe queue once in a while and saves the changes coming from that queue into the database. The websocket logic was just passing the information on to that queue.